# ASP.NET MVC4 + Entity Framework 5 - Incorrect DB name on SaveChanges()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have MVC4 + EF5 app with single connectionString in web.config, and single DBContext using it.

I have a simply Create controller.

I have successfully ran my app in DEV.

I am attempting to move to UAT, which involved new DB, so I updated the connectionString, and on SaveChanges() I get a DBUpdate exception like:

> {"Invalid object name 'DBNAME.dbo.TABLENAME'."}

where DBNAME is my DEV database name. Yet I can see that the connection is being made to correct SQL Server instance. All my AJAX/JSON form methods are connecting to the DB just fine.. it is only when I go to save the form that I get the issue of EF trying to look for wrong DB on correct SQL Server.

If i modify the destination table in such a way that it doesn't fit my model, on SaveChanges() I will instead get exception complaining of the mismatch... so seems like only when the target schema is correct, for some reason EF is falling back to my DEV DB name.

Where could the old DB name be cached? There's no reference to it anywhere now. How can I 'reset' this?

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention I'm using Code First, but the schema already exists.. i just have manually written the model classes, without using DatabaseMigrations.
**EDIT2:** I just re-wrote the entire app using Database First, and am getting the same thing!! What the heck is going on? From where could the name of a database that is not mentioned anywhere in the model or connection string be coming? I've cleaned/rebuilt the solution; published to another web box; deleted Temporary ASP.NET file..  I am utterly lost!

**EDIT3** The exception:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'WRONGDATABASENAME.dbo.WorkspaceRequest'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +404
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +412
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +1363
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData() +59
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +118
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +6384561
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) +6386130
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) +538
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +28
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +256
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +19
   System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues) +270
   System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter) +536

[UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.]
   System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter) +11194398
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options) +833
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() +218

[DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.]
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() +291
```

(sorry for lazy phrasing--i've been at this forever and am getting tired and frustrated)

Comment: The database name comes from the connection string. How are you passing the connection string to your context?

Comment: I have a connectionString name matching my DBContext in my web.config, but I have also tried hardcoding the connection string in the DBContext constructor. The connection string specifies the correct database name name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the issue. Turns out EF consumes ODBC exceptions, and I had an invalid trigger (pointing to the old DB name) on the target table generating the exception that was bubbling up to the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Search the entire solutions for 'WRONGDATABASENAME.dbo.WorkspaceRequest'

You should be able to see it in the XML view of your edmx file.

Also, try dropping all items from edmx and update it again?

Comment: Thanks. Have tried that. That name doesn't appear anywhere in the source. I built a brand new EDMX (didn't have one before--only .cs model classes). Still same issue